# What is the proper way to implement animation in a CCSprite subclass?

Tags: objective-c, cocos2d-iphone

in my game I made a subclass of CCSprite (cocos2d) for my enemies.
Because I want control over animation, from within every instance of this subclass, I had to translate my animation code in my main class, which loads
the enemies, to this subclass.

I found this rather hard but.... after some time it magically started to work.

Unfortunately after creating and setting properties in this subclass I started to have weird crashes. Because they are in cocosDenshion and other places which have nothing to do with my
enemy class and after a research in depth in my code and on the net, I'm convinced its some kind of data corruption and I'm almost completely certain its because I did my enemie class with his animation code completely the wrong way.

To be honest, I cannot even wrap my mind around what is going on here anymore and how this actually works :S...I'm completely stuck. any help is much appreciated!

**So my main questions would be: What is the proper way to implement animation in a CCSprite subclass ? / what am I doing wrong here?**

simplified my code here: (it triggers the animation every 2 seconds to show how I want
to use it)

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Npc : CCSprite 
{
    CCAction *_runAnimation;
    NSString* name;
    int strength;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *runAnimation;
@property int strength;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString* name;

- (Npc*)loadAnimation;
- (void)animate;
@end
```

---

```
#import "Npc.h"

@implementation Npc

@synthesize runAnimation = _runAnimation;
@synthesize name;
@synthesize strength;

-(id) initWithTexture:(CCTexture2D*)texture rect:(CGRect)rect
{
    if( (self=[super initWithTexture:texture rect:rect]))
    {
    }
    return self;
}

- (Npc*)loadAnimation
{

    int lastFrame = 11;
    NSString *creatureFile = @"vis 1";

    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:
     [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.plist", creatureFile]];
    CCSpriteBatchNode* sheet = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:
                                [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@.png", creatureFile]];

    self = [Npc spriteWithTexture:sheet.texture];
    NSMutableArray* animFrames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];     

    for (int x = 0; x < lastFrame; x++) 
    {
        [animFrames addObject:
         [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
          [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ %d.png", creatureFile, x]]];              
    }

    CCAnimation* anim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames: animFrames delay: 0.1];

    self.runAnimation = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:anim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];

    [self runAction:_runAnimation];

    return self;
}

- (void)animate
{
    [self runAction:self.runAnimation]; 
}

- (void)dealloc 
{
    [super dealloc];

    [name release];
}

@end
```

---

```
#import "HelloWorldLayer.h"
#import "Npc.h"

@implementation HelloWorldLayer

+(CCScene *) scene
{
    CCScene *scene = [CCScene node];
    HelloWorldLayer *layer = [HelloWorldLayer node];
    [scene addChild: layer];
    return scene;
}


-(id) init
{

if( (self=[super init])) 
{
    timer = 0; 

    creatureTemp = [Npc spriteWithFile:@"Icon.png"];
    creature = [creatureTemp loadAnimation];
    creature.position = ccp(100,100);
    [self addChild:creature];

    [self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];

}
return self;
}


- (void)nextFrame:(ccTime)dt
{
    timer += dt;
    if (timer > 2.)
    {
        [creature animate];
        timer = 0.;
    }
}

- (void) dealloc
{
    [super dealloc];
}
@end
```

**-------------------EDIT--------------------**

I changed my code with help of a tutorial by Ray Wenderlich: http://www.raywenderlich.com/3888/how-to-create-a-game-like-tiny-wings-part-1

this is I think much closer to what it should be. Unfortunately it still crashes on my iphone (not the simulator) on SimpleAudioEngine (which I implement right) so I still do something wrong.

on top of the Npc class:

```
@synthesize batchNode = _batchNode;
```

the init of the Npc class:

```
-(id) initNpc
{
    if( (self=[super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"vis 1 0.png"]))
    {
        _normalAnim = [[CCAnimation alloc] init];

        NSMutableArray* animFrames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init]; 

        int lastFrame = 11;

        for (int x = 0; x < lastFrame; x++) 
        {
            [animFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vis 1 %d.png", x]]]; 
        }

        _normalAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames: animFrames delay: 0.1];
        self.runAnimation = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:_normalAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];


    }
    return self;
}
```

and the init of the HelloWorldLayer

```
-(id) init
{

    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {
        timer = 0; 


        _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"vis 1.png"];
        [self addChild:_batchNode];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"vis 1.plist"];

        creature = [[[Npc alloc] initNpc] autorelease];
        creature.position = ccp(200,200);

        [_batchNode addChild:creature];

        [self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];

        [[SimpleAudioEngine sharedEngine] preloadEffect:@"super1.mp3"];

    }
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I got it....here is the code:

**Npc.h:**

```
#import "cocos2d.h"

@interface Npc : CCSprite 
{
    CCAction *_runAnimation;

    CCAnimation *_normalAnim;
    CCAnimate *_normalAnimate;

}

@property (nonatomic, retain) CCAction *runAnimation;


- (void)animate;
- (id)initNpc;

@end
```

**Npc.m**

```
@synthesize runAnimation = _runAnimation;
@synthesize batchNode = _batchNode;

-(id) initNpc
{  
    if( (self=[super initWithSpriteFrameName:@"vis 1 0.png"]))
    {
        _normalAnim = [[CCAnimation alloc] init];        
        NSMutableArray* animFrames = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];         
        int lastFrame = 7;        
        for (int x = 0; x < lastFrame; x++) 
        {
            [animFrames addObject:
             [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] spriteFrameByName:
              [NSString stringWithFormat:@"vis 1 %d.png", x]]]; 
        }        
        _normalAnim = [CCAnimation animationWithFrames: animFrames delay: 0.1];
        self.runAnimation = [CCAnimate actionWithAnimation:_normalAnim restoreOriginalFrame:NO];       
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)animate
{
    [self runAction:_runAnimation];
}
```

**in the HelloWorldLayer.m**

```
-(id) init
{

    if( (self=[super init])) 
    {

        _batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"vis 1.png"];
        [self addChild:_batchNode];
        [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"vis 1.plist"];

        timer = 0; 

        creature = [[[Npc alloc] initNpc] autorelease];
        creature.position = ccp(200,200);

        [_batchNode addChild:creature];

        [self schedule:@selector(nextFrame:)];

    }
    return self;
}

- (void)nextFrame:(ccTime)dt
{
    timer += dt;
    if (timer > 2.)
    {
        [creature animate];
        timer = 0.;

    }
}
```

And about the weird crashes in cocosDenshion. That is also solved...it turned out to be a known bug in SimpleAudioEngine where it threw exceptions only when I had an exception breakpoint active. Workaround: made a class for my sound and if I need a exception breakpoint, I comment out the sound...

-- have to say, I do would prefer the:

```
_batchNode = [CCSpriteBatchNode batchNodeWithFile:@"vis 1.png"];
    [self addChild:_batchNode];
    [[CCSpriteFrameCache sharedSpriteFrameCache] addSpriteFramesWithFile:@"vis 1.plist"];
```

inside the Npc class, but that is too advanced oop for me. If anybody knows that, let me know...would be great to know actually, to understand oop better.
But it is not strictly necessary...

Answer (score 2):

You're reassigning self in loadAnimation:

```
 self = [Npc spriteWithTexture:sheet.texture];
```

At that point I stopped reading the code. Since self already is an instance of the Npc class you have to ask yourself why you're doing this in an Npc instance method like loadAnimation.

Comment: thanks for the reply! I actually was aware of this line that it was no good...but I don't know how to do it differently...could you maybe point me in the right direction?